# Facing issue to handle more then two window with selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
public class Abc{
    @Test
    public void test() throws InterruptedException{
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\src\\test\\java\\drivers\\geckodriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get("URL");
    String mainWindow=driver.getWindowHandle();
    Set<String> set =driver.getWindowHandles();
    Iterator<String> itr= set.iterator();
    while(itr.hasNext()){
        String childWindow=itr.next();
        if(!mainWindow.equals(childWindow)){
        driver.switchTo().window(childWindow);
        System.out.println(driver.switchTo().window(childWindow).getTitle());
        driver.close();
        }
    }
    driver.switchTo().window(mainWindow);
    }
}
```

I was using this code for multi window handling and it was working perfectly with two window but with three or four window, sometime driver was not switching on other window.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the window handles before and after opening the new window to get the newly opened one

```
Set<String> beforeSet = driver.getWindowHandles();
// open new window
Set<String> afterSet = driver.getWindowHandles();
afterSet.removeAll(beforeSet);
String newWindowHandle = afterSet.iterator().next();
driver.switchTo().window(newWindowHandle);
```

Comment: OP doesn't have any line of code to `// open new window`. Perhaps all the `WindowHandles` are opened while invoking `driver.get("URL");`

Comment: @DebanjanB what the difference? a new window is being opened, one set should be located before that and the other one after.

Comment: Of coarse there is a difference. As there is no step for `// open new window`, _beforeSet_ and _afterSet_ will be identical and after `afterSet.removeAll()`, _afterSet_ will be NULL

Comment: @DebanjanB The OP is opening a new window. `// open new window` in my answer is a place holder for that action.

Comment: Well, no, OP isn't opening a new window :) observe the question heading _handle more then two window_. Not necessary OP is opening a new window interacting with any element.

Comment: @DebanjanB And how would he have more than one window without opening it?

Comment: Of coarse `driver.get("URL")` can open multiple windows. Check the website naukri.com